# Low signal in my Samsung Galaxy Note 10 5G

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, network-signal

Yesterday, I bought a Galaxy Note 10 5G smartphone that was previously used but it looks like a new one. I inspected the phone before buying it and everything was alright.
However, after inserting the sim , there was a problem in the signal that was too low even though the 4 lines sometimes appear full.

I tried almost every method of solving the issue after googling it like restarting the phone, resetting network settings, deeping into the safe mode and manually choosing a network operator. Yet, restarting my phone seemed to work for several seconds but the issue remained.
Is there a fix to it ?

Keep in mind that when I moved to the city centre, the signal improved significantly (but still not perfect).
And note that my previous phone used to have a really consistent signal with the same sim card in all circulstances.

Comment: Hello Salem! We may need some more information to help. When you say "the signal was too low even though the 4 lines sometimes appear full," how are you determining "low" signal? Slow network speeds? Dropped calls?

Comment: When I go to the city centre and call someone, they tell me that there is some interruption in sound. And when I go back home which is in a rural area, when I type a phone code to determine how much money I have left, it takes so much time to tell me that there is an error connecting (though the code itself is correct). Also, sometimes the logo of "no signal"  appears and sometimes there is signal which is very low (2 or even 1 full line)

Comment: The wifi is working fine though, my problem is only with phone signal

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be difficult to diagnose. It could be that your phone is damaged or it could simply be that the Note 10 5G radio isn't as capable as your previous phone. I've also heard situations of phone cases causing problems for people on certain phones. Hopefully, we can test some possibilities here, but I fear there may be too many. Have you contacted your carrier yet? What have they had to say?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a phone cover/case that has too much metal in it.

But most likely the phone is damaged.  Phones effectively have multiple aerials for RF, wifi and bluetooth.  It sounds like the RF aerial may be damaged or not connected properly.

Take it to a repair shop and they may be able to prove it.

Comment: When I googled the issue, it turned off to be so common in the Galaxy Note 10 series. Smartphones that had just been manufactured experienced the issue so I do not think it is related to some kind of damage